# Android testing on multiplie devices from Jenkins

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, android-espresso

I'm running Espresso test to test my application. The app have a first time login that requires a code from a text message.

The easiest way to get past the the first time login is to keep the same application installed so that the user data remains.

running the command:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

seem to remove the application when the tests are done. Is there any simple way to skip the uninstallation part and just run the tests on all connected devices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended that you not rely on state being already setup on the device, but instead, setup the state you need within the test itself.

That being said, you can install the app with gradle and the run the tests with `adb`.

This assumes a standard default app layout and setup, using `androidx.test` with a recent version of the android gradle plugin.

First install the app and the tests.

```
./gradlew installDebug installDebugAndroidTest
```

Then you can execute the tests:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.your.applicationId.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

This will run your app and keep your app and tests installed.
You can run the `adb` command multiple times in a row and it will execute the tests without rebuilding and reinstalling your app.

Of course, if you make any changes to the app or tests you will need to re-run gradle.

More info:

- [Installing adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)
- [Running tests with adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line)
- [androidx.test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project)
- [Customize your test run](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner#typical-usage)